# Bash output image dimensions of all files with a specific name

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I want to go through the album artwork images in my music folder, and

1. make sure all the album covers are square (width = height)
2. make sure the album covers have a minimum width of 500px

I found several things that do each of these, but I'm painfully slow with bash, and can't quite figure this out.  Closest I've come is this:

```
find /mnt/2TB_1/Music/Archive/Complete -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec echo identify -format "%wx%h" "{}/folder.jpg" ';' -fprint0 /mnt/2TB_1/Music/output.txt
```

This is looking at the correct folder depth.  When I run this, my command prompt shows the dimensions for all the correct folder.jpgs, and the output.txt only file has the paths (without line breaks).  However, I really need them all in one place (and preferably in the output.txt file, since there are a LOT of folder.jpg files to look at).

I wouldn't turn down a bash script that does the filtering I mentioned, but I'm quite willing to settle for an output like:

```
w  xh   path
500x500 /mnt/2TB_1/Music/Archive/Complete/Artist1/Album1/folder.jpg
500x500 /mnt/2TB_1/Music/Archive/Complete/Artist1/Album2/folder.jpg
350x350 /mnt/2TB_1/Music/Archive/Complete/Artist2/Album1/folder.jpg
```

From there, I can just throw it in a spreadsheet and do the analasys.

Comment: Are all your images called `folder.jpg`?

Comment: yes, they are all called folder.jpg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is, or how your files really look but this should be close to what you seem to want:

```
find /mnt/2TB_1 -name folder.jpg -exec identify -format "%G %M\n" {} \;
```

You can add in all your exclusions and depths and things again once it works how you want, or just delete the stuff you don't need in Excel.

If you want the output to a file (called `list.txt`), just use:

```
find ... > list.txt
```

If you want to analyse that file and find images that are not square or that are narrower than 500 pixels, you could just use `awk`, like this:

```
awk -F'[x ]' '($1!=$2)||($1<500)' list.txt
```

The `-F'[x ]'` tells `awk` to split the fields on each line using either the `x` in the dimensions or a space. That means that the width gets put in field `$1` and the height in field `$2`. The maths is then easy.

Comment: This will send results to the console, right?  I want them sent to a txt file, because there will be at least 4000 hits, and will be more data than the console will hold. The analysis I want to do is to find any folder.jpg files that 1) height != width 2) width < 500.  I'm only interested in finding files that match that criteria.

Comment: This is an easy fix : just add `> output_file` at the end of your command and all the output that would have been displayed on the console will be instead written in the `output_file`. Read on bash's I/O streams and their redirection if you want to learn more on that topic.

Comment: that got me really close.  It didn't add line breaks, but I managed to get it into the spreadsheet anyway.  Final result was: `find /mnt/2TB_1/Music/Archive/Complete -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -name folder.jpg -exec identify -format "%G %M\n" {} \; > /mnt/2TB_1/Music/output.txt` - not sure why I needed to go to a depth of 3, but whatever. Thanks!